# Calculate series resistor value for LED on 220 Vac RMS supply

Tags: resistors, ohms-law

The traditional way to find the resistor value I can find on the internet is:

```
(Input Voltage - Forward Voltage) / Current
```

In my case, the Input Voltage is 200 Vac, forward red LED voltage is 2 V and the current is 0.02 A.

That means: (220 - 2) / 0.02 = 10900.0. That implies I should be able to put a 10900 ohms resistor and put my LED on 220 Vac.

So that's what I did, I put my LED in this configuration:

[image]

[ modified schematic, removed diodes connected in opposite ]

Rather than using 10.9K, I used 10K and 1K resistor in series.

When I put that on 220 Vac, the whole thing just burns. When I search google for the proper resistor value, some say use 47K, some say use anything above 100K and some say use 200K. I have in fact, used 47K throughout my life, and it works flawlessly. So it got me curious: why doesn't it obey the simple formula of using 10.9K Ohm resistor?

Comment: the input voltage is not 220 V

Comment: 1) 240VAC has a peak voltage of 340V. 2) 20mA will dissipate more then 4W in the resistor. 3) Search for capacitive dropper instead.

Comment: 340VAC should have a resistor value of 16900.0 ohms, I don't think it will do the job either. I know how to use capacitive droppers, but that's not the point. Here a resistor of 47K of 1/4th watt is proven to work fine. I just want to know why the math doesn't agree here, why I need a resistor that's way higher than the math suggests? If I use 47K, isn't the current for the LED 0.00723 AMPs (assuming peak voltage is 340VAC)? How come the LED light with that small amount of current?

Comment: The math works fine. You have to take into account the power dissipated in the resistor. 16.9k would still dissipate close to 3W. Even 47k is over a Watt. Modern high brightness LEDs already emit a fair amount of light with half a milli.

Comment: The LED has a peak reverse voltage of only a few volts. The leakage current through the diodes will put almost the whole 220 Vac RMS across it, the peaks of which are around 311 V and -311 V. Instead, you'd want a diode in reverse across the LED to keep the LED Vrrm below 0.8 V. The two 1N4007s are a waste of time as connected in inverse parallel - they don't do anything. But the circuit has wider problems and has been answered before on this site.

Comment: Your modified circuit won't work. The diode is pointing the opposite way to the LED. Note: be careful editing your question that you don't remove stuff that is referenced in the answers already. If you do it makes the answers look stupid. In this case add captions below your various schematics.

Comment: This question serves a great example of how not to drive an LED from line voltage.

Comment: @S.Goswami I have to ask. Why not a neon bulb? They are sooooo simple. Zero complexity.

Comment: After your most recent edit your schematic is still incorrect. No current can flow with the LED and diode having their cathodes connected as shown.

Comment: Oops that's true. The LED or diode needs to be flipped in order for it to work. I edited it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, there's a lot of confusion out there (3K+ views), so let's clear this up.

First, remember we're dealing with 220VAC, which is 311V peak or 622V peak to peak.

Second, adding a diode is smart because it prevents reverse current during the negative half cycle, which can damage the LED over time. If you don't use a diode, a reverse current will flow during the negative half cycle. I've experienced that this can damage the LED fast. However, when I added a diode, the LED had a much longer lifespan, and I had no failures. Also, adding a Zener diode anti-parallel to the LED will be a better choice in this case.

[image: LED with Diode]

Here's what it looks like in the scope with the diode vs without the diode:

[image: With vs Without Diode]

With or without a diode, the LED flickers at 50Hz, which isn't great to look at.

To solve that issue, you can use a full wave bridge rectifier (like DB107, MB10S, MB10F, etc). It gives you about 100Hz DC voltage (for a 50Hz input). Add a suitable capacitor to smooth out the flickering at 100Hz (`use C = I / (frequency * rippleVoltage)` to calculate the value). We'll get to this later.

Note that different colored LED need different voltages and currents to light up. I did an experiment with a bench power supply with 1mV accuracy. Here's what I found:

#### RED LED:

```
0.77mA @ 1.850VDC
Starts glowing barely visibly at: 1.420VDC.
Max (point before LED fails or flickers): 2.250VDC (consumes 100mA current, brightness decreases beyond this)
```

[image: Red LED]

#### Green LED:

```
0.12mA @ 2.230VDC
Starts glowing barely visibly at: 1.950VDC
Max: 4.500VDC (fails)
```

[image: Green LED]

#### BLUE LED:

```
0.16mA @ 2.500VDC
Starts glowing barely visibly at: 2.300VDC
Max: 4.3V (fails at 0.1 Amps; gets very hot after 3.6VDC with no increase in light output)
```

[image: Blue LED]

#### YELLOW LED:

```
0.56mA @ 1.870VDC
Starts glowing barely visibly at: 1.650VDC
Max: 2.150VDC (flickers and gets very hot beyond this)
```

[image: Yellow LED]

---

Please note that the above experiments were conducted at an ambient temperature of approximately 28°C. The performance of LED can change with temperature, so results may vary under different conditions. Also, in these experiments, the power supply functioned as a constant voltage source, meaning the voltage was kept steady while the current was allowed to vary.

---

For a bright red LED, use 1.990VDC (about 5mA):

To drop to 1.990V from 220VAC, you can either use a voltage divider (with suitable current), or a single resistor. In the case of a single resistor, you can use a 61K resistor:

```ruby
(220 * Math.sqrt(2) - 1.99) / 0.005
=> 61827.39674441618
```

A close common value is either 68K or 56K.

For a slightly lower glow (but still bright), you can use 1.9VDC which draws around 0.001 or 1mA of current. So the resistor value will be:

```ruby
(220 * Math.sqrt(2) - 1.9) / 0.001
=> 309226.98372208094
```

In this case, a 309K resistor will be good. A common value near this is 300K or 330K.

Keep in mind that the resistor value calculation assumes a constant LED voltage drop and current. However, these parameters can fluctuate based on temperature changes. For example, some LED exhibit a decrease in forward voltage drop of approximately 2mV for every 1℃ increase in temperature.

If the LED is powered by a constant voltage source, it will shine brighter as the temperature rises due to an increase in current consumption as well.

---

Now, add a full wave bridge rectifier after the resistor, then a capacitor to stabilize the LED glow. If we run the LED at 1.9VDC, the LED will draw 1mA. To calculate the capacitor value, use `C = I / (f * Vr)`.

Where:

```
I is the load current.
f is the frequency of the AC signal (after full-wave rectification, this will be twice the input frequency, so 100 Hz in our case).
C is the capacitance.
```

Rearranging the formula:

```
C = I / (f * Vr)
```

For a 5% ripple (5% of 1.990V = 0.099), the needed capacitor value is `C = 0.001 / (100 * 0.099) = 0.000101F or 101uF`. A close available value is 100uF.

---

So, a 100K resistor is enough to make the red LED glow bright!

Also note that green LED have higher luminious efficacy at low current due to how human eye's sensitivity to green light.

That's why a 100K resistor works well :)

Comment: OK, so lot of confusion here too. 220VAC is 311 peak and 622 peak-to-peak. And adding the diode only reduces reverse voltage and current by some amount but as it is not an ideal component it means the diode will still leak some reverse current and there will be some negative bias over the LED. Without the diode, the LED flickers just like with diode.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yeah it should be "peak" instead. Also, the diode here isn't for reducing LED flickering, but to enhance its lifespan. Without the diode, the LED lights up for half of the AC cycle, but during the other half, it experiences ~35V reverse flow. The resistor doesn't limit this voltage to 2V due to minimal current. Most LEDs can withstand a maximum reverse-biased voltage of 5V. Without a diode, I've had many failures, but with one, the LED works indefinitely. Also - adding a zener diode will be better in this case. Updated answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

There will be about 220V over the resistor while 20mA flows through it.

It will dissipate 4.4W as heat, which is quite a lot and you would need a resistor that can handle it or it will burn. Which is why it's really not practical to use resistors in this case.

The other thing that might cause burning is that in general LEDs are specifed to handle about 5V in reverse and you  are connecting it to 220 VAC, in which case there will be peaks of 310V in reverse over the LED.

Do note that mains voltage can be dangerous and lethal if you are inexperienced working with mains voltage circuits.

Comment: AFAIK, all the LED indicators I buy in India, which are rated for 220VAC, uses just one 47K or 56K resistor of 1/4th watt. Even my power strip has that! They get hot easily, but they last for years without any problem. That got me curious...

Comment: @S.Goswami Are you sure you really mean LEDs, instead of neon lamps? Power strips generally have neon lamps.

Comment: Nope, I really meant LED. I'm aware of neon lamps. Here's a crappy 3 minute youtube video you can fast forward and watch: https://youtu.be/Z4f04H0Wl18 (the guy uses 0.5w resistor, which makes more sense, but 1/4th watt isn't uncommon). If you got 220VAC, you can test that. Also, I can't understand why particularly 47K or 56K even though they will cause a small amount of current flow through the LED that shouldn't be able to light it up

Comment: @S.Goswami In that video he runs the 1/4 watt resistor with a ~0.5 watt load for a few seconds and with a large metal plug connected to sink heat.  You can do that for a few seconds, but it'll quickly get very hot and then burn.  Lights made to run off of mains are probably not normal 2 or 3v LEDs, but rather higher voltage ones made of several junctions in series to reduce reverse current.

Comment: @S.Goswami a 47k resistor will still pass over 6mA peak current, which is easily enough to light any modern LED very brightly.

Comment: There has been an edit that makes a single 1N4007 block reverse current to the LED.  A bypass diode would limit reverse voltage even without balancing reverse currents from LED and 1N4007 (and this might have been the original idea but got botched up), but a single blocking diode will likely work well enough.  So I'd suggest editing your answer in that respect to make it fit the edited question again.

Comment: @user107063 Sure, but a series diode is not perfect, it has reverse leakage current and capacitance, so while it may be better and work well enough for some time, it does not mean it's good, and it does not mean the circuit has also other problems, such as resitor not being rated for voltage past 200V or enough power.